# How to turn screen of a tizen wearable web app on after some event

Tags: tizen, tizen-web-app, tizen-wearable-sdk

I'm developing a tizen wearable web app.
I'm using tizen 3.0.
My app can do work in the background. (At least it should be able)

When something happens within my app when screen is off, I want to turn it back on again and show a popup (just as an example)

Apparently [tizen.power.turnScreenOn()](https://developer.tizen.org/development/api-references/web-application?redirect=https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/3.0.0/org.tizen.web.apireference/html/device_api/wearable/tizen/power.html#PowerManager::turnScreenOn) is deprecated since 3.0 and will be removed in the next release.

tizen-sdk told me to use [tizen.power.request("SCREEN", "SCREEN_NORMAL")](https://developer.tizen.org/development/api-references/web-application?redirect=https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/3.0.0/org.tizen.web.apireference/html/device_api/wearable/tizen/power.html#PowerManager::request).
But this does not turn my screen on. As far as I understand the API documentation this just tells to leave the screen on (until it is released)

So what I currently have:

```
function bringApplicationToFront() {
  //here I would use tizen.power.turnScreenOn():
  tizen.power.request("SCREEN", "SCREEN_NORMAL");
  var app = tizen.application.getCurrentApplication();

  //app is launched just in case it is currently in background
  tizen.application.launch(app.appInfo.id, () => {
    tau.openPopup("pageToShow");
    tizen.power.release("SCREEN");
  }
}
```

background support is enabled in config.xml:

```
<tizen:setting background-support="enable" encryption="disable" hwkey-event="enable"/>
```

So question is:
Is there a way to turn the screen on once an event occured in my app?

Comment: Which event do you want to use .... i tried tizen.power.request("SCREEN", "SCREEN_NORMAL"); straight ....it is working ....

Answer (score 0):

maybe if you put this line in your config.xml file

```
<tizen:setting background-support="enable" encryption="disable" hwkey-event="enable"/>
```

In my project only work with this line.
This is for web service run in background too, so you can run everything.

Comment: I already use background-support. I updated my question with the relevant config.xml snippet.

Answer (score -1):

As I know...
For regular web UI application, background operation is NOT guaranteed. Especially furthermore in commercial target for battery consumption issue.

I use native service application (for Hybrid app) and app control to launch or wake up web UI application.

Comment: partners-level certificate is not an issue for me.

Comment: The link you provided is for TV only.

Comment: I am sorry for a incorrect link. (I edited answer a little) BTW, When I make wearable application, I use native service application (for Hybrid app) and app control to launch or wake up web UI application. I recommend that way. Good luck.